# Docker-compose postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

Не могу понять что не так

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  redis:
    image: "redis:7-alpine"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/redis_data:/var/lib/redis/data

  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: <some_name>
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

```
docker compose up
```

```
db-1     | 
db-1     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db-1     | 
db-1     | 
db-1     | 2023-09-29 07:40:52.770 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.0 (Debian 16.0-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
db-1     | 2023-09-29 07:40:52.770 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db-1     | 2023-09-29 07:40:52.770 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db-1     | 2023-09-29 07:40:52.772 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1     | 2023-09-29 07:40:52.779 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-09-29 07:40:50 UTC
db-1     | 2023-09-29 07:40:52.787 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

При попытке подключения к localhost:5432, выдает что роли postgres нет, хотя вроде явно не указывал имя пользователя. Mac OS

Comment: Зашел в контейнер - посмотрел роли

Comment: postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS |

Comment: Пользователь есть но ошибка остается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот мой конфиг, возможно будет полезен:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db_postresql:
    container_name: db_postresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
    image: postgres:latest
```

Comment: нет, тут явное указание просто, спасибо